# Yii2 Custom http exceptions views

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In the application login I have the following code that throw `...HttpException` on logging errors:

```
// common/models/LoginForm.php which is called from the backend SiteController actionLogin method as $model = new LoginForm();

public function loginAdmin()
    {
      //die($this->getUser()->getRoleValue()."hhh");
      if ($this->getUser()->getRoleValue() >= ValueHelpers::getRoleValue('Admin') && $this->getUser()->getStatusValue() == ValueHelpers::getStatusValue('Active')){
        if ($this->validate()){
          return \Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30:0);         
        }
        else{
          throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('Incorrect Password or Username.');

        }       
      }
      else{
        throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('Insufficient privileges to access this area.');
      }
    }
```

It is working fine, but I want to customize the page the rendered with each of `NotFoundHttpException` and `ForbiddenHttpException`. I tried to search the [Yii2 api](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-forbiddenhttpexception.html#__construct()-detail) to find any parameters that may define view in the construct of the object but I could not find that. So, is there any way to custom the view of the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Mihai P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880627/mihai-p) (Thank you) answer, I have got this answer. I opened the file of the error class at [**`vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorAction.php`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-framework/blob/master/web/ErrorAction.php) and I have found that it has a public property for view, so, I decided to use it and hence I defined it in the `error` array of the `actions` method as follows:

```
public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
                'view' => '@common/views/error.php',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Finally, in `common` folder I had to create a new folder named `views` and fill it with a view file called `error.php` with the following simple code

```
<?php
$this->title = $name;
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $message;
echo "<br>";
echo $exception;
```

The three variables in the view `$name, $message and $exception` are supplied from the ErrorAction object and they could be found in the [last lines of that file](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-framework/blob/master/web/ErrorAction.php)

```
...
else {
            return $this->controller->render($this->view ?: $this->id, [
                'name' => $name,
                'message' => $message,
                'exception' => $exception,
            ]);
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php

You can see that it uses an external action to handle the errors

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

You can either create your own ErrorAction file that extends the default one and use yours instead of the default one from Yii, or just comment out that action and create a normal actionError and put it in there.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer inspired me to get my answer.